# Swift - NSCoding a Set<Enum>

Tags: swift, encoding, enums, set, nscoding

I'm currently using *NSCoding* on a custom class to try encoding and decoding two Set<> Objects with no success.

My issue is that those Set Objects (**baseSet** & **extraSet**) both are Sets of another Object, which is, respectively **baseEnum** & **extraEnum**.

I've tried:

```
public enum baseEnum: String {
  case X = "foo"
  case Y = "foos"
}
 (...)   

public class MyClass: NSObject, NSCoding {

   var baseSet = Set<baseEnum>()
   baseSet.insert(baseEnum.X)
    (...)

   public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
      aCoder.encode(baseSet, forKey: "baseSet")
      aCoder.encode(extraSet, forKey: "extraSet")
   }
}
```

The encoding itself fails, throwing the error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue
>   encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109f959c0'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x18409ed8c 0x1832585ec 0x1840ac098 0x1840a45c8 0x183f8a41c 0x184a523cc 0x1849f8d0c 0x184a04ad4
>   0x184a523cc 0x10157704c 0x101577180 0x184a523cc 0x101486f08
>   0x101486f9c 0x184a523cc 0x10145f884 0x10145fc3c 0x184a523cc
>   0x184a0bad4 0x18697e350 0x1869b60b0 0x186b97548 0x186b98c80
>   0x186b8d0e4 0x1869f2000 0x186a74ba4 0x10442d19c 0x10443a9bc
>   0x186a74aa0 0x186b650cc 0x186aa68f8 0x186aa1fcc 0x186984704
>   0x186a81d80 0x186a7a758 0x186984130 0x1869a518c 0x101414cb8
>   0x101417abc 0x10147c2c4 0x1013ce2b0 0x1013ce2d4 0x10442d19c
>   0x10443f574 0x10147abf0 0x101516e00 0x101516edc 0x101635d40
>   0x1016520cc 0x101651968 0x101646eac 0x10163ba6c 0x101641750
>   0x10163fa04 0x10166106c 0x10166081c 0x10165ebf8 0x183fd7b34
>   0x183fe3554 0x183fd762c 0x18471172c 0x184716ee4 0x184712d58
>   0x18404d9f4 0x184047404 0x184046c2c 0x18404479c 0x183f64da8
>   0x185f4a020 0x18df84758 0x101516f5c 0x1839f5fc0)

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `NSCoding` rather that `Codable`?

Comment: To use `Set` as `NSCoding` object, the `Set` needs to be convertible to `NSSet`. Unfortunately, you cannot convert `Set` of non-`@objc` enum to `NSSet`. Use `Set<String>` or find another way.

Comment: @AshleyMills The main reason is that the project is now quite big and everything else is working with NSCoding, which is working properly. I was hoping I could find a way to make this work without refactoring everything to support Codable.

Comment: @OOPer Thank you for the clarification! That being said, using Set<String> is an option I still haven't explored properly but I have a feeling it won't work. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: You most probably don't need to convert anything else to work using `Codable`, you can simply use `Codable` for this specific class.

Comment: @DávidPásztor eventually managed to make it work doing exactly that! Thank you all for your input.